# Not able to add data to geom_rect in ggplot in pipe version; however without pipe (%>%) it works

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I could not understand where is the error in this code.

The following code works fine

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(wt, mpg)) +
geom_rect(data=data.frame(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 4, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
        aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
        fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.5)
```

However the same code while using %>% or in dplyr version gives error

```
mtcars %>% 
ggplot(aes(x= wt, y= mpg)) + geom_point() +
geom_rect(data=data.frame(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 4, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
        aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
        fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.5)
```

The following error is displayed
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'wt' not found

Edit: Since there could be mapping issue as pointed below
however the following works; just the data part is removed from geom_rect

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 4, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
        fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.05)
```

Thanks for your time and suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

In your pipe version, the mapping is specified in `ggplot` which gets applied to `geom_rect` also. Specify it in `geom_point` instead.

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x= wt, y= mpg)) +
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 4, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
        aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
        fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.5)
```

Comment: Does that mean geom_rect is dependent on geom_point for drawing the desired rectangle. Thanks.

Comment: Since the mapping are separately defined in geom_rect() should it conflict with the mapping in ggplot()..

Comment: Mappings defined in the `ggplot` call are applied to all geometries unless the same aesthetic is specified in the mapping for the geometry. So `geom_rect` had the aesthetic `x = wt` because the mapping in `geom_rect` didn't explicitly specify `x`.

Comment: However the following works. ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 4, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
            fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.05)

Comment: In that example, the `data` for `geom_rect` is `mtcars`. You don't get an error because `x = wt` is valid because `wt` exists in `mtcars`. In the original example, the `data` was different for `geom_point` and `geom_rect`. The `geom_rect` `data` didn't have the column `wt`.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Got the clarity. is x = wt is still a hidden argument in geom_rect.?

Comment: You could keep the original as is and use `inherit.aes = FALSE` in `geom_rect()`.